# Extract link's title value

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, append, extract, title

How can I append link's title value as a link's text. I have this code:

```
<a href="#" title="Title value"></a>
```

...and after clicking on it I want to have something like this:

```
<a href="#" title="Title value">Title value</a>
```

Thank you!

Comment: This `<a>` tag will not be displayed until you give something like this `<a href="#" title="Title value">Some Value</a>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).prop("title"));
});
```

Comment: You can also just do `this.title`.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).attr('title'));
}
```

should work.

Maybe you want to give your `<a>` tag a special ID, so you can reference it.